# How create Grafana dashboard for view metric and her confidence intervals?

Tags: grafana, dashboard, confidence-interval

Research Grafana how tool for create dashboard for view metric and her confidence intervals.

Prepare data frame and import to PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE public.rnd_ci (
datetime TIMESTAMP,
yhat_lower float,
yhat_upper float,
yhat float,
y float
);
```

Create dashboard
use PostgreSQL data source

```
SELECT
  datetime AS "time",
  yhat_lower,
  yhat_upper,
  yhat,
  y
FROM rnd_ds
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(ds) AND
```

use Time series panel

[image]

But I want to create this variant

[image]

How create this variant dashboard?

Comment: Please clarify what in your current graph doesn't satisfy you?

Comment: I will want to create graph where upper and low interval is pipe, how lower variant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming what you want is to fill area between upper and lower graphs:

1. Panel options > Overrides > <kbd>+ Add field override</kbd>
2. Field with name. Select name of your upper field, presumably `yhat_upper`
3. <kbd>+ Add override property</kbd>
4. `Graph styles > Fill below to`
5. Select name of your lower field, presumably `yhat_lower`.